# Youtube videos Fullscreen not working

Tags: drupal, youtube, mediaelement.js

The full screen button does not works.
My sources are youtube videos and i use HTML5 and mediaelement 2.13.2

exemple :

```
<video width="650" height="360" id="player1" preload="none">
<source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ID" />
</video>
```

Then i allow the fullscreen like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery('video').mediaelementplayer({
 allowfullscreen: 'true'
});
</script>
```

I'm using a drupal module to implement mediaelement js file in the web site [video humour](http://feed-buzz.fr/sites-de-buzz/vid%C3%A9os-humour)
The module give me an exemple and here, the fullscreen works.

Can you help me ?

thank's

Comment: Since your videos are from youtube, is there a reason why you aren't using the youtube embed code instead?

Comment: It is because i want to have another skin